# Vue.js to display Pusher data Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue.js, pusher, and laravel to build a real-time chat application. I can receive the information from Pusher just fine; I can output the json into the console and it has the right information. I just wasn't sure how to take the messages that already exist in the database that I grab using fetchMessages, and append the new Pusher messages that were received and display them in real-time.

**Displaying messages**

```
<div id="app">
    <article v-for="message in messages">
        <h3> User ID: @{{ message.user_id }}</h3>
        <p> @{{message.body}} </p>
    </article>
</div>
```

**Vue**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
    messages: []
},

ready: function() {
    this.fetchMessages();

    var pusher = new Pusher('key_here', {
        encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('cars');
    channel.bind('App\\Events\\UserHasNewMessage', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        /*
             I can output my pusher data to the console just fine. 
             But how can I append this data to the existing messages?
        */
    });
},

methods: {
    fetchMessages: function() {
        this.$http.get('/api/messages', function(messages){
            this.$set('messages', messages);
        });
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Just push the new messages on to the messages array

Comment: Like 'this.messages.push(data)'? It says that push is undefined.

Comment: You can't use 'this' because it's a different function context. You need to alias `this` outside the function, and then use that alias.

Comment: You can store vue instance into variable `const vm = new Vue({...})` and then you can use `vm.messages.push(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You have three ways to do this:

## On ES5:

1. Add `.bind(this)` at the end of the function, to be able to access `this` inside the function

   ```
   channel.bind('App\\Events\\UserHasNewMessage', function(data) {
        this.messages.push(data);
   }.bind(this));
   ```
2. Assign `this` to a variable, and use that variable inside the function

   ```
   var that = this;
   channel.bind('App\\Events\\UserHasNewMessage', function(data) {
        that.messages.push(data);
   }.bind(this));
   ```

## On ES6:

3. Use the [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions), so you can use `this` inside the function

   ```
   channel.bind('App\\Events\\UserHasNewMessage', (data) => {
        this.messages.push(data);
   });
   ```